# Play 2.3 Action not found in production mode (start, stage)

Tags: routes, action, playframework-2.3, production

I have the application with subprojects on play 2.3. While was being developed there were no problems (run in IDE or `activator run`). In production mode (dist, stage or `activator start`) the application runs without error, but does not find any `Action` (Action not found For request 'GET /').

What is happening?

Tried the url of all the projects and some are working

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.

Even though it is stated in the documentation that "if not specified `router` - default is `conf/routes`", I define `application.router=root.Routes` in `application.conf` and rename router as `root.Routes'.